# Image segmentation and object separation in 3D using Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, image3d, segmentation

I currently work on an image segmentation scenario to detect cell nuclei in 3D using *Mathematica*. The data I have are image stacks in the [TIFF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TIFF.html) file format. I would like to keep the sequence of image processing steps as small and simple as possible, since I expect the segmentation pipeline to work for several image stacks. I uploaded an [example image stack](http://ge.tt/9teGemr/v/0?c) containing several cell nuclei objects. Here is a screenshot of the image stack after creating an `Image3D` object out of it.

```
smallCropped = Image3D[Import["...\\smallExample.tif"], 
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image: raw image stack as Image3D object]

The image shows about 40-50 cell nuclei objects. Note that due to a different spacings in the z-dimension the objects appear flattened. However, this should not have any influence on the segmentation itself. If you have a look at the data you will find out that the signal to noise ratio ([SNR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)) is very high. The segmentation of the cell nuclei objects should therefore be feasible. Here is a GIF animation of the image stack moving through the stack in the z-dimension:

[image]

I applied what seems to me as the most straight forward approach to segmentation in *Mathematica* ([Binarize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html) and [MorphologicalComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MorphologicalComponents.html)):

```
Show[#, ImageSize -> 512] & /@ {binary = Binarize@smallCropped, 
  Image3D[Colorize@MorphologicalComponents@binary]}
```

[image]

So far so good. As you can see from the colorized components matrix on the left, several cell nuclei objects are assigned the same object label (*e.g.* the large pink object). Hence, preprocessing steps and a more sophisticated segmentation procedure seem to be required.

After going through many types of image filtering and segmentation in *Mathematica* I got lost at some point and ended up plugging together various different filtering and segmentation steps. In most of the cases, the more I tried the worse the results got ;) I know that there is no golden rule for segmentation in image processing but the task of correctly segmenting the objects in this scenario seems to me not that difficult and I wonder if there exists a nice and easy way.

The [WatershedComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WatershedComponents.html) method tries to separate connected objects. Since this method currently only works in 2D in *Mathematica* I implemented a method that first segments all the images of the stack slice by slice using a combination of `GradientFilter`, `WatershedComponents`, `Binarize`, `MaxDetect` and `DistanceTransform`. I then tried to merge the results from this 2D segmentation to end up with a 3D components matrix. I didn't put the code here but you can see the output of these two steps below (left: 2D `WatershedComponents` result, right: 3D result after merging).

```
compsMatrix = 
  SelectComponents[
     WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[#, 1], 
      MaxDetect[DistanceTransform@Binarize@ImageAdjust@#], 
      Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", .3}], "Count", 
     10 < # < 2000 &] & /@ Image3DSlices[Binarize@smallCropped]
```

[image]

This is where I am at so far. The segmentation accuracy and object separation still looks poor to me and I am curious what steps might improve the results. My questions are:

**1. What preprocessing steps (e.g. filters) built in Mathematica might
    be suitable to increase the segmentation accuracy in this case? Is there a combination of standard filters that might work here?**

**2. How could I improve the separation of objects in 3D?**

**3. What about `WatershedComponents` for `Image3D` objects?**

**Edit: response comment on Erosion**
A suggestion in the comments was to use `Erosion`. I know that erosion helps to separate objects.however, in this scenario it did not help and I would lose much information about the objects.

**Edit: response to answer by UDB**

Thanks to the nice approach proposed by [UDB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9453/udb) I could go on with the 3D segmentation problem and try the approach with my data. At first the results looked very promising but when taking a closer look, I have to say that the solution proposed does not provide a satisfying result. I have checked the results for the test image stack provided above I then used the functions proposed by [UDB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9453/udb):

```
distcompiled = 
  Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}}, 
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, 
     ii}, {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[(i - ii)^2, {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[
     Min@Table[disttab[[i, ii]] + dist[[ii, j, k]], {ii, dimi}], {i, 
      dimi}, {j, dimj}, {k, dimk}]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];

Options[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D] = {Padding -> 1};
EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[im3d_Image3D, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{dist3d, i, j, k, ii, dimi, dimj, dimk}, 
   dist3d = 
    Developer`ToPackedArray@
     ParallelMap[
      Round[ImageData[
          DistanceTransform[#, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]^2] &, 
      Image3DSlices[
       Image3D[ArrayPad[ImageData[im3d, "Bit"], 1, 
         Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]]];
   If[OptionValue[Padding] != 0, 
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       ParallelMap[
        If[Times @@ Dimensions[#] == Total[Flatten[#]], # + 
           1073741822, #] &, dist3d, {1}];];
   dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@distcompiled[dist3d];
   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, -1];
   Image3D[Sqrt@dist3d, "Real"]];
```

As you can see, I changed the `CompilationTarget` to "C" and added a missing comma after the local variable disttab in the distcompiled function. I then packed the function together and gave it a name:

```
splitSegmentation3D[img3d_Image3D] := 
 Function[{image}, 
   Image3D[Colorize[
     MorphologicalComponents[
      ImageMultiply[
       Binarize[
        LaplacianGaussianFilter[
         EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[
          ColorNegate[
           Binarize[
            ImageMultiply[MaxDetect[#], #] &[
             EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[image]], 5]]], 1]], 
       image]]]]][img3d]
```

As proposed I set the threshold for accepted maxima to 5 in this function. For binarization I use the proposed `TotalVariationFilter` as pre-processing step and then do a simple `Binarize`. I then do the last of the pipeline using the function `splitSegmentation3D`:

```
{smallCropped = Image3D[Import["...\\smallExample.tif"],
prepro = TotalVariationFilter[smallCropped],
bin = Binarize[prepro],
comps = splitSegmentation3D[Binarize[prepro]]}
```

[image]

The components image looks just like the components image in the answer except for the colors...good. But when taking a closer look at the segmentation by slicing through the images in z-dimension, you see the details. I put the results of the complete image processing chain next to each other (from left to right: original, preprocessed, binary, components image):

[image]

I see multiple problems with this approach. First, using `TotalVariationFilter` as preprocessing step also blurs the image which results in many connected objects. Second, the splitting performs heavy over segmentation resulting in splitted objects. Third, many objects seem to be rounded by the segmentation. I think this results from the `EuclideanDistanceTransform3D` in combination with `ImageMultiply`.

I don't think that a perfect segmentation is possible on my data, but it should work out for at least some of the objects.

Comment: I get the feeling you really want to compensate for the flattened dimension. Once this is taken into account, you might use `Erosion` to "shrink" cells before `MorphologicalComponents`, and then somehow use the partitioning again on original data.

Comment: I don't think that the z-dimension spacing plays a crucial role if I understand your comment right. It is just that the objects appear to be a little more flat. But this should not change the segmentation. About `Erosion`: I know about morphological operations, but as far as I can tell it doesn't help with the separation if the objects overlap a little more.

Comment: The lack of definition in the vertical scale prevents the use of simple erosion techniques in order to separate the nuclei without losing a lot of info. Are you able to get more vertical samples density?

Comment: @belisarius: No. There is currently no possibility to increase the sample density in z. It is due to the optical properties of the microscope the images are aquired with. I am thinking about using something like Watershed segmentation in 3D to cope with the problem. But since there is no 3D implementation in MMA I will have to implement it or use another software.

Comment: You can correct for the flattening of the vertical range using `BoxRatios`.

Comment: @g3kk0 could you comment on what additional details you require for an answer to meet the conditions in your bounty?

Comment: Yes. The approach in the answer gives interesting results but doesn't give a satisfying segmentation of the objects. The objects are heavily oversegmented and seem to get spherical by the segmentation method. I think the ideas mentioned are very good but they need further optimization to achieve better segmentation. Especially the binarization and preprocessing need to be improved.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Introduction

I propose a solution to this object separation problem, which simply was inspired by one of the application examples of `DistanceTransform`. It uses a simple method to split virtually connected (blurred) objects in 3D. A LoG filter (Marr-Hildreth operator) is detecting edges in the Euclidean distance transform by this doing a tesselation required to split the abovementioned blurred objects. Since the `DistanceTransform` function presently is lacking 3D functionality, an own implementation of Euclidean distance transform is provided.

Using this method you might end up with this label image:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But one step after another. This is our test data set for the moment:

```
img3d = Image3D[
  ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[{3, 4, 5}], {{5, 10}, {20, 15}, {25, 30}}] + 
   ArrayPad[DiskMatrix[{5, 6, 3}], {{3, 8}, {18, 13}, {33, 26}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### A self-made 3D distance transform

However, we still have to have a 3D distance transform. I will provide a poor man's solution of a 3D Euclidean distance transform, utilizing the built-in 2D `DistanceTransform` and adding some stuff according to algorithm 1 of the 1994 Pattern Recognition paper by Saito and Toriwaki entitled ["New algorithm for Euclidean distance transformation of an n-dimensional digitized picture with applications"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0031-3203(94)90133-3), vol. 27, no. 11, pp. 1551-1565.

The following code provides an auxiliary function later on used to do the Euclidean distance measurements in the third dimension. It receives a 3D matrix `dist` consisting of a stack of 2D distance transformed images, whereas the *squared* Euclidean distances are assumed here. Along the stack direction, for each voxel it searches the minimum sum of the squared distance and the provided intermediate result:

```
distcompiled = Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}},
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, ii},
    {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[(i - ii)^2, {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[
     Min[disttab[[i, All]] + dist[[All, j, k]]],
      {i, dimi}, {j, dimj}, {k, dimk}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
   (*this might be set to "C" if a compiler is installed*)
   ];
```

What still has to be defined is the function `EuclideanDistanceTransform3D` itself:

```
Options[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D] = {Padding -> 1};
EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[im3d_Image3D, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{dist3d, i, j, k, ii, dimi, dimj, dimk},

   dist3d = 
    Developer`ToPackedArray@
     Map[Round[
        ImageData[
          DistanceTransform[#, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]^2] &, 
      Image3DSlices[
       Image3D[ArrayPad[ImageData[im3d, "Bit"], 1, 
         Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]]];

   If[OptionValue[Padding] != 0,
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       Map[If[Times @@ Dimensions[#] == Total[Flatten[#]], # + 
           1073741822, #] &, dist3d, {1}];
    ];

   dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@distcompiled[dist3d];

   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, -1];

   Image3D[Sqrt@dist3d, "Real"]
   ];
```

This function assumes a binary `Image3D` handed over using the variable `im3d`.

The first part of the function does nothing but splitting the 3D stack into a sequence of 2D images and mapping them into the `DistanceTransform` function, wheras the result is re-squared. A one-voxel padding is applied using the `Padding` option provided.

The second part is circumventing the behavior of `DistanceTransform` when receiving images only consisting of 1's, in such a case it again returns an image purely filled with 1's, however, it should be full with `Infinity` entries, since there was not any 0. So we add $$2^{30}-2=1073741822$$ in such cases, by this ensuring that $$2^{31}-1$$ is never being exceeded as long as $$2^{15}=32768$$ is taken as largest extent in either of the volume dimensions: $$2^{30}-1+(2^{15})^2=2^{31}-1=2147483647$$.

In the third part we just use the auxiliary function already defined above.

In the fourth part the padding made in the beginning is being eliminated.

In the last part an `Image3D` is being assembled as return value, whereas for all elements of `dist3d` the square root is extracted, since we want to provide the Euclidean distances.

Now we have this `EuclideanDistanceTransform3D`.

### A first test

Let us make a first test:

```
EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, we are interested in those voxels indicating the local maxima:

```
MaxDetect[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We might want to exclude some local maxima with not exceeding some certain distance values (3 in this example; this makes no difference to the result above for this test data set):

```
Binarize[ImageMultiply[MaxDetect[#], #] &[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d]], 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using these local maxima voxels, we apply another `EuclideanDistanceTransform3D` to measure the distances *from* them (we need to negate the maxima voxel intermediate result):

```
EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[
  ColorNegate[
   MaxDetect[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d]]]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What follows is the detection of 3D edges inside this second distance transform using an LoG filter:

```
LaplacianGaussianFilter[
  EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[
   ColorNegate[MaxDetect[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d]]]], 
  1] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By binarizing the latter we will obtain a template to tesselate our data set, so objects might be split as intended. Here is the full image processing chain:

```
Function[{img3d},
  Image3D[
   Colorize[
    MorphologicalComponents[
     ImageMultiply[
      Binarize[
       LaplacianGaussianFilter[
        EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[
         ColorNegate[
          Binarize[
           ImageMultiply[
              MaxDetect[#], #
              ] &[EuclideanDistanceTransform3D[img3d]], 
           3(*allow only maxima with distance values > 3*)
           ]
          ]
         ], 1(*LoG filter kernel size*)
        ]
       ], img3d
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ][img3d]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### A second test

To apply this method to the `smallCropped` data set provided above, I recommend to do an edge-preserving smoothing before binarization:

```
img3d = Binarize[TotalVariationFilter[smallCropped]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What simply has to be done here is to apply the same image processing chain given above, whereas the minimum threshold for accepted maxima was set to 5 here instead of 3 (as for the synthetic example).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please compare this output with the original data set:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We are done.

Problems I still see here may be mainly caused due to the non-convexity of a certain number of objects in this data set.

### Parallelized version of Euclidean 3D distance transform

I am happy to show you a parallelized version of my self-made 3D distance transform. Again, we use a compiled auxiliary function to treat the 3rd dimension, but this time with two option set: `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True`, so we later on will be able to hand over a series of 3D lists, and we have enabled the execution of these series in parallel:

```
distcompiledparallelized = Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}},
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, ii},
    {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[(i - ii)^2, {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[Min[disttab[[i, All]] + dist[[All, j, k]]], {i, dimi}, {j, dimj}, {k, dimk}]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   (*this should be set to "WVM" if a compiler is not installed*)
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

Even though Wolfram virtual machine does a good job here, we have turned on C compilation.

Now we come to the function itself:

```
Options[EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized] = {Padding -> 1};
EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[im3d_Image3D, 
   OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{dist3d, forwardtransposition, backwardtransposition, 
    addmargin},

   backwardtransposition = Ordering[Reverse[ImageDimensions[im3d]]];
   forwardtransposition = Ordering[backwardtransposition];

   dist3d = 
    Developer`ToPackedArray@
     Map[Round[
        ImageData[
          DistanceTransform[#, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]^2] &, 
      Image3DSlices[
       Image3D[ArrayPad[
         Transpose[ImageData[im3d, "Bit"], forwardtransposition], 1, 
         Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]]];

   If[OptionValue[Padding] != 0,
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       Map[If[Times @@ Dimensions[#] == Total[Flatten[#]], # + 
           1073741822, #] &, dist3d, {1}];
    ];

   addmargin = 
    Ceiling[#1/#2]*#2 - #1 &[Dimensions[dist3d][[3]], $ProcessorCount];

   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, addmargin}}];

   dist3d = 
    Function[{len, procs}, 
      dist3d[[All, 
         All, # ;; Min[# + Ceiling[len/procs] - 1, len]]] & /@ 
       Range[1, len, Ceiling[len/procs]]][
     Last[Dimensions[dist3d]], $ProcessorCount];

   dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@distcompiledparallelized[dist3d];

   dist3d = Join[Sequence @@ dist3d, 3];

   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -addmargin - 1}}];

   dist3d = Transpose[dist3d, backwardtransposition];

   Image3D[Sqrt@N@dist3d, "Real"]
   ];
```

First of all we make sure that the 3D data will be transposed in a way that the extent of the 1st coordinate is smaller than the 2nd and 3rd, by this generally minimizing the computational load of `distcompiledparallelized` called later on. To manage this, we determine appropriate lists `forwardtransposition` and `backwardtransposition` for the respective `Transpose` calls later on.

Then we do the processing of the series of 2D images as done in the initial version.

Once this was done, we do some preparations for the parallelization. We have to make sure that all 3D sublists we want to hand over to `distcompiledparallelized` have the same dimensions. However, depending on the `im3d` dimensions and the `$ProcessorCount` this requires some padding. We do this padding solely at the upper margin of the 3rd dimension.

Once we have done the padding, we continue with equally splitting `dist3d` depending on both its 3rd dimension and the `$ProcessorCount`, so `distcompiledparallelized` can be called.

What remains to be done is some maintenance: Re-joining the `dist3d`, removing the margin (together with the overall padding), and undoing the transposition.

The last very effective way for speeing up is to numericalize `dist3d` before drawing the square root ...

### A further approach to the object separation problem

Looking on the `smallCropped` data set one might get the feeling that its height requires stretching in order to let the cells appear as spheres (anisotropy correction o f course will have some influence to our distance based approach), we may assume a factor of approx. 3:

```
smallCroppedinterpolationfunction = 
  ListInterpolation[ImageData[smallCropped, "Real"], Method -> "Spline"];
smallCroppedinterpolated = 
  ParallelTable[
   smallCroppedinterpolationfunction[i, j, k], {i, 1, 
    Dimensions[ImageData[smallCropped]][[1]], 0.33}, {j, 1, 
    Dimensions[ImageData[smallCropped]][[2]]}, {k, 1, 
    Dimensions[ImageData[smallCropped]][[3]]}];
smallCroppedstreched = Image3D[smallCroppedinterpolated, "Real"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then we again should do a TV filtering, but for fluorescence data we better should assume a Poisson noise:

```
img3d = Binarize[
  TotalVariationFilter[smallCroppedstreched, Method -> "Poisson", MaxIterations -> 100]
]
```

Without option specification (or by setting `Method -> "Cluster"`) `Binarize` takes ["Otsu's method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method) doing some minimization of the intra-class variances.

The distance transformed `img3d` then looks like this:

```
EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[img3d] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Having detected the maxima inside this distance transform (and selecting those exceeding a certain minimum), we can look how both the distance field between these maxima and the tesselation look like:

```
EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[ColorNegate[
   Binarize[
    ImageMultiply[MaxDetect[#], #] &[
     EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[img3d]], 
    15]]] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
LaplacianGaussianFilter[
  EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[ColorNegate[
    Binarize[
     ImageMultiply[MaxDetect[#], #] &[
      EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[img3d]], 15]]], 
  3] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, here is the code doing all the steps:

```
Function[{im3d},
  Image3D[
   Colorize[
    MorphologicalComponents[
     ImageMultiply[
      Binarize[
       LaplacianGaussianFilter[(*Marr-Hildreth operator*)
        EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[
         ColorNegate[
          Binarize[
           ImageMultiply[
              MaxDetect[#], #
              ] &
            [EuclideanDistanceTransform3Dparallelized[im3d]], 
           15(*allow only maxima with distance values > 15*)
           ]
          ]
         ], 3(*LoG filter kernel size*)
        ]
       ], im3d
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ][img3d]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may complain that small cells are missing, well, I did my best (mixed-sized cells in an object separation problem make things sophisticated), and you may play with the two parameters, i.e. the LoG filter kernel size and the minimum maxima threshold. I personally think that it should not be considered an artifact that almost all cells touching the data set margins have been canceled.

Hope you enjoy the parallelized Euclidean 3D distance transform. It now can easily handle large volumes (not exceeding 32768 for all dimensions). If there is anybody who is inspired to extend my self-made 3D distance transform approach to `ManhattanDistance` and `ChessboardDistance`, please feel free to do so...

### Addition: Extended 3D Distance Transform

I am happy to introduce my extended parallelized solution `DistanceTransform3D` for `Image3D` data, in analogy to the kernel function `DistanceFunction` presently only processing `Image` data, it now includes these distances: `EuclideanDistance`, `ManhattanDistance`, and `ChessboardDistance`.

We utilize three different compiled auxiliary functions:

```
eucldistcompiledparallelized = Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}},
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, ii},
    {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[(i - ii)^2, {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[
     Min[disttab[[i, All]] + dist[[All, j, k]]], {i, dimi}, {j, 
      dimj}, {k, dimk}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", (*should be set to "WVM" if no compiler is installed*)
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];

manhdistcompiledparallelized = Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}},
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, ii},
    {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[Abs[(i - ii)], {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[
     Min[disttab[[i, All]] + dist[[All, j, k]]], {i, dimi}, {j, 
      dimj}, {k, dimk}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", (*should be set to "WVM" if no compiler is installed*)
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];

chessdistcompiledparallelized = Compile[{{dist, _Integer, 3}},
   Module[{dimi, dimj, dimk, disttab, i, j, k, ii},
    {dimi, dimj, dimk} = Dimensions[dist];
    disttab = Table[Abs[(i - ii)], {ii, dimi}, {i, dimi}];
    Table[
     Min@Map[Max[#] &, 
       Transpose[{disttab[[i, All]], dist[[All, j, k]]}]], {i, 
      dimi}, {j, dimj}, {k, dimk}]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", (*should be set to "WVM" if no compiler is installed*)
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

The 3D distance transform reads now:

```
Options[DistanceTransform3D] = {Padding -> 1, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance};
DistanceTransform3D[im3d_Image3D, thresh_Real: 0., OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Module[{dist3d, forwardtransposition, backwardtransposition, addmargin},

   backwardtransposition = Ordering[Reverse[ImageDimensions[im3d]]];
   forwardtransposition = Ordering[backwardtransposition];

   Switch[OptionValue[DistanceFunction],
    EuclideanDistance,
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       Map[Round[
          ImageData[
            DistanceTransform[#, 
             DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance, 
             Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]^2] &, 
        Image3DSlices[
         Image3D[ArrayPad[
           Transpose[ImageData[Binarize[im3d, thresh], "Bit"], 
            forwardtransposition], 1, 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]]];
    ,
    _,
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       Map[ImageData[
          DistanceTransform[#, 
           DistanceFunction -> OptionValue[DistanceFunction], 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]] &, 
        Image3DSlices[
         Image3D[ArrayPad[
           Transpose[ImageData[Binarize[im3d, thresh], "Bit"], 
            forwardtransposition], 1, 
           Padding -> OptionValue[Padding]]]]];
    ];

   If[OptionValue[Padding] != 0,
    dist3d = 
      Developer`ToPackedArray@
       Map[If[Times @@ Dimensions[#] == Total[Flatten[#]], # + 
           1073741822, #] &, dist3d, {1}];
    ];

   addmargin = Ceiling[#1/#2]*#2 - #1 &[Dimensions[dist3d][[3]], $ProcessorCount];

   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, addmargin}}];

   dist3d = 
    Developer`ToPackedArray@
     Function[{len, procs}, 
       dist3d[[All, 
          All, # ;; Min[# + Ceiling[len/procs] - 1, len]]] & /@ 
        Range[1, len, Ceiling[len/procs]]][
      Last[Dimensions[dist3d]], $ProcessorCount];

   Switch[OptionValue[DistanceFunction],
    EuclideanDistance,
    dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@eucldistcompiledparallelized[dist3d];
    ,
    ManhattanDistance,
    dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@manhdistcompiledparallelized[dist3d];
    ,
    ChessboardDistance,
    dist3d = Developer`ToPackedArray@chessdistcompiledparallelized[dist3d];
    ];

   dist3d = Join[Sequence @@ dist3d, 3];

   dist3d = ArrayPad[dist3d, {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -addmargin - 1}}];

   dist3d = Transpose[dist3d, backwardtransposition];

   Switch[OptionValue[DistanceFunction],
    EuclideanDistance,
    Return[Image3D[Sqrt@N@dist3d, "Real"]];
    ,
    _,
    Return[Image3D[dist3d, "Bit16"]];
    ];
   ];
```

We generate a synthetic data set:

```
SeedRandom[2405];
img3d = Image3D[Table[If[RandomReal[] > N[1/1000], 1, 0], {10}, {20}, {15}]];
```

We do a short performance test:

```
eucldist3d = DistanceTransform3D[img3d, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
manhdist3d = DistanceTransform3D[img3d, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance];
chessdist3d = DistanceTransform3D[img3d, DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];
```

Here we have the results:

```
ImageAdjust[ColorNegate[#]]& /@ {img3d, eucldist3d, manhdist3d, chessdist3d}
```

[image: test data set]
[image: Euclidean distance]
[image: Manhattan distance]
[image: Chessboard distance]

Hope one day the same 3D functionality will be included in the built-in `DistanceTransform`.

Comment: That's one hell of a first answer! +1

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks very much! I can't wait to try it on my data ;)

Comment: The non-convexity of certain objects could indeed be a problem which might be fixed by merging some of the objects back together after they have been split by your proposed method. I will try the processing chain on my data and keep you informed.

Comment: There is a comma missing in the function distcompiled after disttab.

Comment: Thanks, have corrected this missing comma, and also have improved the return value computation in `distcompiled`(could easily get rid of one of `Table` functions).

Comment: @g3kk0: Are you buying a beer to UDB? That is the least you can do. This is way beyond a small nudge to help in someone's homework. Send him (her?) a postcard. And do not forget to acknowledge this post in your paper.

Comment: @Hector: Yeah, good idea with the beer and postcard ;) Maybe a postcard with a beer on it?

Comment: Wow, thanks very much for the improvements and time you investigated on this problem! I especially like the parallelization, since runtime is always an issue when having large datasets. I think that the approaches you might be very helpful also in other segmentation attempts. I totally agree with you: The object separation algorithm you propose seems to be the best one can do with the data in order to split the objects. Therefore, I accepted your detailed answer and awarded the bounty to you. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, one thing I still think about is the handling of the maxima obtained by `MaxDetect`, I presently think using some `MeanShift` based approach these maxima (handled n-fold, n is the respective rounded distance) possibly could be more concentrated (without destroying correct separatedness), but this would be something you might try out by yourself. - Thanks for the whole lot of points! Next time you might send a postcard :-)

Comment: @UDB i think the people at Wolfram heard you :) `DistanceTransform` now works on 3D images as well with the distances you mentioned

Comment: @Ali Hashmi Yes, as far as I can remember, it was added to the kernel from version 10 on, published in July 2014. I was in touch with Wolfram people early in 2014, so maybe I could facilitate 3D functionality of `DistanceTransform`. Please note that the now built-in 3D function also provides the `SquaredEuclideanDistance`.

Answer (score 8):

In this approach the main idea is to pre-process the images rather than processing 3D Image. Lets look at some properties of the images.

```
im = Import["...\\smallExample.tif"]

(*Resize it for speeding up the process*)
img = ImageResize[#, 50] & /@ im;
```

Lets look at image 20 (others are similar) to see it's histogram. 0-0.05 shows us the Black background. The brightest color is about 0.5-0.55.

```
ImageHistogram[img[[20]], Frame -> False, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, Ticks -> {Range[0, .6, .05]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image: Histogram of the image 20]

The main idea towards the solution is to use the ColorFunction to pre-process the images. [Blend](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blend.html) linearly interpolates between colors. It can be used in 2D or 3D. In the sample images the dark grey tones means the objects below parts under the cross section planes and the brighter the parts closer to plane. (Side note binarizing early in the pre-processing, we loose a lot of information.) Ok, lets see what we can do with ColorFunction and Blend. We use the ranges defined in histogram. We can combine or use varying ranges best suits to our purpose.

```
(*Define the Blended Color Function*)
cf = (Blend[{{0.0, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {0.05, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0., 0., 0.], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {0.09, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0.27450980392156865`, 0.6039215686274509, 0.22745098039215686`], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {0.27, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0.5843137254901961, 0.30196078431372547`, 0.30196078431372547`], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {0.3, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0.4117647058823529, 0.20392156862745098`, 0.20392156862745098`], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {0.4, \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[0.5686274509803921, 0.5372549019607843, 0.], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}, {1., \!\(\*
 TagBox[ColorSetterBox[RGBColor[1., 1., 1.], "Swatch"], Setting]\)}}, #1] &);

(*Reconstruct the image with new colors*)
ii = ((Raster[ImageData[#], ColorFunction -> cf] // Image)) & /@ img
```

[image: Blended images]

From the images the we can see that green colors are in fact not on the cross section plane. The brownish and yellow colors are. By playing color ranges one can isolate the underneath part of the objects. With out knowing the actual shape of the objects it is hard to correct or preprocess further the images. From this point on one can use [MeanShiftFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MeanShiftFilter.html), [BilateralFilter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BilateralFilter.html) or other relevant ones.

Corrected ranges of blended image

[image: Corrected ranges of blended image]

```
 (*Constructing 3d image*)
 im = Image3D[
  ii, "Byte",
  Background -> Black,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  (*ColorFunction\[Rule]cf2,*)
  Method -> {"InterpolateValues" -> True,
  "SampleLayers" -> 200,
  "FixedSampleDirection" -> True}
 ]
(*Find the Components*)
Colorize@MorphologicalComponents@(Binarize[im, .32] )
```

The final image

[image: Final image 3d]

The results can be further improved by using other filters in 2d like FillingTransform etc.

Comment: Nice approach, thanks! I will try your approach on the data and keep you informed.